# Where did the menu bars from my applications go in GNOME Shell?

Tags: windows, gnome, menu

I'm running ubuntu 11.10, and all the menu-bars (File, Options, etc ) from applications like gedit & co are gone.

For some applications that is not a problem, because there are still icons I can click on, but for other applications I need to access their menu bar. So how can I get the menu-bars back?

**EDIT:**
I'm using **gnome-shell** not unity.

Comment: I'm using gnome-shell on 11.10, and this does not happen for me.  Yes, unity's installed as well.  You could try backing up your home directory and creating a fresh home directory.  It might just be a config file or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out & solved the problem:

Because of a LightDM bug, I was always logged into Unity. Then, on a terminal I would do:

`gnome-shell --replace &`

If you do that, GNOME Shell does indeed start, but the programs' menubars are not visible. If I however circumvent the the LightDM bug and make sure I get logged into GNOME Shell right away, the menubars appear as expected. so this seems to be some kind of weird LightDM / Unity / GNOME Shell interaction bug.

Answer (score 3):

Disable any globalmenu extension, then in the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `org/globalmenu` and uncheck *enabled*. Log out and log back in.