# How do I permanently disable extensions in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome

I installed a Gnome Shell plugin that disables the menu bar, and places it on the top panel. I disabled and deleted the plugin files, but now I can't see the menu bar.

I tried 'sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell', followed by 'sudo apt-get install gnome-shell', but it didn't seem to work.

How can I place the menu bar back on the frame? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you use another user account?

Answer (score 2):

I posted the solution on askubuntu but can't remember where. You might want to try this:
http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-Gnome-Shell-suggestions-and-solutions?pid=14528#pid14528

Disable any globalmenu extension, then in the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to org/globalmenu and uncheck enabled. Log out and log back in.

Comment: Your post is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75465/where-did-the-menu-bars-from-my-applications-go-in-gnome-shell/75641#75641  Click your username to see your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool`
then you can disable unwanted extensions from there